# C++11 VS2013 class POD member initialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I've looked everywhere for an explanation for this but am coming up short. I'm seeing this behavior from the VS2013 v120 platform toolset, but when I set the toolset to v90 (the VS2008 toolset) everything is uninitialized. I believe this is due to some change in C++11, but it could also be an anomaly of the v120 platform toolset.

**Can anyone explain what's going on here on the C++/C++11 level? That is, why is `b` zeroed out? And why is `j` not also zeroed out? (i.e. why is the behavior different for structs than for classes)**

Also, I know the way I'm outputting data is undefined behavior, please ignore that. It's easier to post that way here than a debugger window. This is running on 32-bit, so pointers are the same size as an unsigned int.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
  int a,
      *p;
};

class Bar {
public:
  Bar(){}
  int a,
      *p;
};

struct Jar {
  Jar(){}
  int a,
      *p;
};

int main() {
  Foo f;
  Bar b;
  Jar j;
  std::cout << std::hex; // please excuse this undefined-behavior producing test code, it's more simple to show this than a debugger window on SO (this is on 32-bit)
  std::cout << "f: " << ((unsigned*)&f)[0] << ' ' << ((unsigned*)&f)[1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "b: " << ((unsigned*)&b)[0] << ' ' << ((unsigned*)&b)[1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "j: " << ((unsigned*)&j)[0] << ' ' << ((unsigned*)&j)[1] << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
f: cccccccc cccccccc  
b: 0 0  
j: cccccccc cccccccc
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the disassembly I see associated with `Bar b;` The __autoclassinit2 is zeroing the memory. It is not part of the constructor but rather is zeroed before the constructor call.

```
  Bar b;
00886598  push        8  
0088659A  lea         ecx,[b]  
0088659D  call        Bar::__autoclassinit2 (0881181h)  
008865A2  lea         ecx,[b]  
008865A5  call        Bar::Bar (0881109h)
```

Comment: You're asking why some uninitialised variables have one value and others have a different value? That's because uninitialised variables have indeterminate values. As you point out, using those values gives undefined behaviour. So the only answer to your question is "because anything could happen".

Comment: @Apriori: In all three cases all members contain garbage values. Nothing is "zeroed out" here. If you see zeros in the output, they are purely accidental, as are any other values. I.e. your zeros are garbage zeros, not deterministic zeros.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: I'm talking about undefined behavior in outputting type punning the values and printing them out for the sake of example. However in my scenario (on the machine in front of me) I look at them in the debugger and this is what I see. Surely looking at variables in the debugger does not trigger undefined behavior.

Comment: @Apriori: Fair enough. What you see in the debugger is the contents of the uninitialised memory, which could contain anything.

Comment: @Apriori debugger or not, the data be evaluated by your *code* is sourced from indeterminate variable content. And by the letter of the standard, even *evaluating* variables of indeterminate content invokes UB. In practice it isn't likely to exhibit anything besides the "garbage" term so many like to throw around, but none-the-less, it is an ill-formed program.

Comment: @AndreyT: This is running in a debug build. 0xCC is written to uninitialized stack variables. So the fact that the values are zero for `b` means that the code generated for the constructor is doing it. So the zeros are not garbage values. Furthermore I get compile errors if I try to access members of `f` or `j` because they are uninitialized, hence the type punning. I do not get compile errors for accessing members of `b`, rather I type pun there for uniformity of the example.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Will the compiler generate a constructor with code in it to initialize indeterminate content?

Comment: @Apriori in all three cases, *default initialization* takes place, which is defined concretely in C++11 § 8.5,p11 and C++11 § 8.5,p6. In the case of `Foo`, no user-provided default constructor is delivered, so the compiler generates one for you which does nada to the POD members. In the cases of `Bar` and `Jar`, both have user-defined default constructors (which are called during default-initialization) but again provide no initialization for the POD members. Whether a class or struct makes no difference (they are both "class-types" per the standard).

Comment: And fwiw, clang 3.4 on my Mac gives, `f: 1f30 20 b: 1f34 20 j: 1f38 20` in release-mode 32-bit, `f: 300 700 b: f00 1300 j: 1c00 2100` in release-mode 64-bit.

Comment: @Apriori: Compiling your code in VS2013 Update 2 in Debug configuration for 32-bit (and 64-bit) targets I get `cccccccc` in all outputs. I don't know how you managed to get that `0` output, but in any case there's no meaningful explanation for it. In all three cases the variables are uninitialized. If your (older? pre-Update 2?) version of the compiler somehow managed to generate dedicated code for zeroing `b` out, I'm afraid the rationale for it is lost forever in the sands of time.

Comment: @AndreyT: I'm willing to accept this may be just a compiler hiccup. It's odd though because I'm on an unrelated machine now, and I'm seeing the same output from VS2013 that I saw before with a 0s in `b`. In help-about I see that I'm running 12.0.21005.1 REL. But yes, I know it does look like a fluke.. but I think it's a little more than that. (I'm not saying it's aliens, but...)

Comment: @Apriori My compiler version is `Version 12.0.30501.00 Update 2`, so maybe you should update? Hopefully that fixes the behavior you're observing.

Comment: @Praetorian: I followed your advice and my help-about now reads as yours, `12.0.30501.00 Update 2`. But after a clean and rebuild I am still seeing 0s. I've also updated the question with the assembly I'm seeing generated.

Comment: @Apriori: This article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sdl/archive/2012/03/08/guarding-against-uninitialized-class-member-pointers.aspx suggests that your zeroing `__autoclassinit` call can be a consequence of `/sdl` compiler switch (and corresponding project setting), which attempts to guard against uninitialized member variables of pointer type, i.e. `p` in your case.

Comment: @AndreyT: Wow! Yes! That is definitely it! I turn off SDL and the class is `0xCC` initialized as expected, I turn it on and it is zeroes. What it really wierd to me me about this feature (besides that it exists) is that it zeroes the whole object int and all, not just the pointer as the article suggests. The zeroing behavior does go away if I remove the pointer member. It's also odd that it does not happen for classes/structs `f` and `j`. Perhaps it only happens for classes (not structs) when the compiler has actually generated code for the constructor body (rhetorical)?

Comment: @AndreyT: IMO this seems like an undesirable "feature" and I'll be turning it off from now on. Thank you for the great link and insight. If you feel like writing this up as an answer I'll happily accept it. You may keep in mind that I may edit the question in the future to include a debugger screenshot and exclude the `cout` code.

Comment: @Apriori: It looks like @Praetorian wrote about `/sdl` in his answer even before I wrote my comment about it.

Comment: @AndreyT: I didn't see that it had been edited, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All your types contain data members that are built-in types, so none of them will be zero-initialized unless you do one of the following (taking the example of `Foo`):

Initialize the members in the default constructor:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() : a(), p() {}
  int a,
      *p;
};
```

or non-static data member initializers (*brace-or-equal-initializer*)

```
class Foo {
public:
  int a = 0,
      *p = nullptr;
};
```

or leave `Foo` unchanged, and value initialize the instance

```
Foo f{};
```

---

Using the original example, I cannot reproduce the result you observe using VS2013, 32-bit Debug build. The output I get is

```
f: cccccccc cccccccc
b: cccccccc cccccccc
j: cccccccc cccccccc
```

---

**EDIT :** I am able to reproduce the behavior where `b` is being zero-initialized. This happens if you enable the `/sdl` (*Security Development Lifecycle checks*) compiler switch (under Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General).

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161081.aspx) for the switch:

> When `/sdl` is enabled, the compiler generates code to perform these checks at run time:
>   — `...`
>   — Performs class member initialization. **Automatically initializes all class members to zero on object instantiation (before the constructor runs)**. This helps prevent the use of uninitialized data associated with class members that the constructor does not explicitly initialize.

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sdl/archive/2012/03/08/guarding-against-uninitialized-class-member-pointers.aspx) even mentions the `__autoclassinit` function, although the heuristics he lists don't exactly match what we're observing because the behavior of this feature [has changed between VS2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161081%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and VS2013.

Also worth nothing is that the compiler seems to not only distinguish between aggregates (`Foo`) and non-aggregates (the other two), which makes some sense, but, for some truly bizarre reason, it will only perform this zero-initialization if you use the *class-key* `class`, and not `struct`, in the class definition.

Comment: +1 Worth noting, the third option has markedly different behavior depending on whether the aforementioned class provides a user-defined default constructor that does *not* provide a proper initializer list (such as `Bar` and `Jar`).

Comment: Is your platform toolset set to v120? I'm not sure if there is an explicit option to enable/disable C++11 language features, but if there is an it's been shut off please make sure it's on instead. I'm running in the default configuration, that is it's a fresh project just to test this.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that I see zeros in the Bar object as well if I remove the constructor, and add a virtual method.

Comment: @Apriori Yes, toolset v120 (it's the only version I have installed). And I don't know of any options to enable/disable C++11 mode in MSVC. By adding a `virtual` function you've added a vtable pointer to the class, which AFAIK, VC places as the first member, so you really shouldn't be seeing any zeros in that case. I get `b: f1dae8 cccccccc`.

Comment: @Praetorian: I mean that I see zeros for the members in the debugger when there is a virtual function, not in the output. I think that the question might have been better asked using debugger screen-shots rather than console output, but I'm hesitant to change it now after there has been some discussion on it. I've tried this now on a second machine with VS2013 and I still see the zeros for `b`. However, I did also try it with placement new (with no parenthesis after the class name) which I would've guessed would have place zeros in `b` too, however it did not.

Comment: @Apriori I don't see the `__autoclassinit2` call in the disassembly window. What happens if you placement new `Bar` into a buffer you've previously filled with 0xFF? Also, try getting rid of all includes, including `iostream` (and the `cout` statements) and then look at the assembly. You certainly have something strange going on.

Comment: @Praetorian: I don't see the behavior when I call placement new. Which "makes sense" because it looks like the `__autoclassinit2` is used for a value initialization of the class before the constructor call (i.e. it's not part of the constructor's code). I won't include the assembly for that here because it's somewhat long and messy, I guess because it's in debug. I've stripped out all includes and the uses of `cout` for the scenario without placement new, and I still see the `__autoclassinit2` and the 0s. Of course the placement new version needs `#include <new>` though.

Comment: @Praetorian: Thank you! awesome! Yes this is what it is, SDL. When I turn it off the 0s go away. And yes, the behavior doesn't quite match. For instance if the pointer member is not present the class is not zeroed. Also, if the pointer is present then the entire class is zeroed (the int too), so yes as you mention the rules of what is getting zeroed doesn't quite match what is in the article. It's also quite weird that it doesn't happen for structs in the same way as classes (they are supposed to be the SAME!), and also that it doesn't happen when the synthesized constructor is present.

Comment: @Praetorian: Perhaps it doesn't do the zeroing whenever the compiler doesn't generate any code for the constructor (there might be an appropriate term here) or when the user specified it themselves. In any case I'm glad to know what's going on, and this is a "feature" I will be turning off from now on.